# angular factory - how do i evaulate function and get property value

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code in my angular service.

```
 var tstObject = {
    isAllow: false,
};

    var getData = function () {
        var tstData = tstService.get(_myData);

        if (tstData != null)
            return tstData
        else
            return tstObject;
    }

    factory.auth = getData();
```

I am trying to get `isAllow` property in controller as following

```
 if (!myService.auth().isAllow) {

 }
```

It complains `auth()` is not function.
How i can get property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initialising `auth` you are executing the `getData` function. That would mean that `factory.auth` will contain the result, which in your case is an object, not a function.

So, to fix that, what you should be doing is:

`factory.auth = getData;` and then `auth` would refer to the getData function.